# Node.JS, CLI with VSCode not finding path to NPM modules, launch.json

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to write a command line program to use via node.js and CLI module. VSCode is not finding `.require('cli')` so no intellisense.

Then when I launch for debug it isn't looking in the right place, it's looking at `APP\npm_modules\cli.js` when it is `APP\npm_modules\cli\cli.js`.

I do have cli installed both locally and globally *and* I have a `NODE_PATH` environment pointing accordingly.

The same code works correctly when run at the command line, so it's a VSCode issue. Perhaps, there is a different editor that offers debugging that I should consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. Turns out that I had enabled the debugger to break on all exceptions and as `.require` resolves, it is looking in several places, eventually the module is found, but there are a number of caught exceptions along the way. I was stuck at looking at the first exception.